# Is Apple MFI Approval required to use WIFI-Serial solutions in iOS Apps?

Tags: ios, wifi, mfi, peer

I am developing an iOS accessory. I want to connect this accessory with the iPhone. I have read that Bluetooth Classic solution requires MFI. Also Bluetooth Low Energy solution is not a great choice for me because of the limitations in data transfer speed. Can i use WiFi ad-hoc (peer to peer) connection without a MFI approval via bonjour? And if yes, can i distribute the app to the App Store? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Information on what is and isn't covered by the MFi program is available [here](https://mfi.apple.com/MFiWeb/getFAQ.action) but in summary an IP connection over WiFi isn't covered by MFi.

Bonjour and TCP/UDP networking is a standard part of iOS so you should have no issues with app store approval on that basis.

If you use an ad-hoc WiFi network you will need to consider how you will get the user to connect to your WiFi network as you cannot make the connection through APIs.  You may want to consider the Wireless Accessory Configuration (WAC) feature in order to simplify the process of connecting your peripheral to an existing WiFi network; this does require MFi membership.